# Error on trying to build --prod or serve --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to build my app for production, after resolving all the errors, there is one error I can't seem to figure out.

when running ng build --prod, the following error occurs:

> ERROR in D:/1.Work/2.Projects/Application/Quintiles/IHRegistery/4.UI/iHreg/src/$$_gendir/app/pages/visit/component/visitInfo/visitInfo.component.ngfactory.ts (3860,30): Property 'Visit' does n
>   ot exist on type 'VisitInfoComponent'.

And this is my visit component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Visit } from '../../../../model/Visit';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { VisitService } from '../../visit.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { APIConstants } from '../../../../helpers/Constants/const-apis';
import { Message } from '../../../../model/Message';

@Component( {
  selector: 'cmp-visit-info',
  templateUrl: 'visitInfo.html',
  styleUrls: ['visitInfo.scss'],
} )
export class VisitInfoComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input( 'visitItem' ) visitItem: Visit;
  visitObj: Visit;
  myForm: FormGroup;

  // itemObj: Visit;

  createObj: boolean = true;

  message: Message = new Message();

  constructor( private visitService: VisitService,
               private apiConst: APIConstants,
               private route: Router,
               private fb: FormBuilder ) {
    this.visitObj = new Visit();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group( {
      visitDate: [null, Validators.required],
      weight: [null, Validators.required],
      height: [null, Validators.required],
      lowPressure: [null],
      highPressure: [null],
      heartRate: [null],
      temp: [null],
      surg: [null],
      dent: [null],
      phys: [null],
      ortha: [null],
      labAss: [null],
      imag: [null],
      trans: [null],
      treat: [null],
      lastComp: [null],
    } );

    this.myForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe( data => this.onValueChanged( data ) );

    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now*/
  }

  onValueChanged( data?: any ) {
    if ( !this.myForm ) {
      return;
    }
    const form = this.myForm;

    for ( const field in this.formErrors ) {
      // clear previous error message (if any)
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control = form.get( field );

      if ( control && control.dirty && !control.valid ) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
        for ( const key in control.errors ) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();

    /*this.itemObj = this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.itemObj = params; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        console.log('params',this.itemObj);
        if(this.itemObj.id){
            this.createObj=false;

            this.visitObj = this.itemObj;
            /!*this.visitObj.id=this.itemObj.id;
            this.visitObj.visitDate=this.itemObj.visitDate;
            this.visitObj.bloodPressureHigh=this.itemObj.bloodPressureHigh;
            this.visitObj.bloodPressureLow=this.itemObj.bloodPressureLow;
            this.visitObj.dentalProcedures=this.itemObj.dentalProcedures;
            this.visitObj.complicationLastVisit=this.itemObj.complicationLastVisit;
            this.visitObj.heartRate=this.itemObj.heartRate;
            this.visitObj.height=this.itemObj.height;
            this.visitObj.weight=this.itemObj.weight;
            this.visitObj.userId=this.itemObj.userId;
            this.visitObj.imagingProcedures=this.itemObj.imagingProcedures;
            this.visitObj.labAssessmentsProcedures=this.itemObj.labAssessmentsProcedures;
            this.visitObj.orthopedicProcedures=this.itemObj.orthopedicProcedures;
            this.visitObj.patientId=this.itemObj.patientId;
            this.visitObj.physiotherapyProcedures=this.itemObj.physiotherapyProcedures;
            this.visitObj.temperature=this.itemObj.temperature;
            this.visitObj.transfusionLastVisit=this.itemObj.transfusionLastVisit;
            this.visitObj.surgicalOperationProcedures=this.itemObj.surgicalOperationProcedures;
            this.visitObj.treatmentLastVisit=this.itemObj.treatmentLastVisit;*!/

        }else {
            console.log('No params');
        }


    });*/
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log( 'visit-info', this.visitItem );
    // console.log('visit-info is empty', this.helper.isEmpty(this.visitItem));
    if ( this.visitItem !== undefined ) {
      this.visitObj = this.visitItem;
      this.createObj = false;
    } else {
      this.createObj = true;
    }
  }

  submitVisit() {
    console.log( 'submit' );
    if ( this.createObj ) {
      this.createVisit();
    } else {
      this.updateVisit();
    }
  }

  createVisit(resolve?, reject?) {
    this.visitObj.userId = this.apiConst.getLocalStorageData( this.apiConst.LSUSERID );
    this.visitObj.patientId = this.apiConst.getLocalStorageData( this.apiConst.LSPATIENTID );

    console.log( 'create Obj', this.visitObj );

    this.visitService.createPatientVisit( this.visitObj ).subscribe( res => {
      if ( res.success && res.returnObject !== null ) {
        this.message.type = 'success';
        this.message.body = 'Visit Create Successfully';
        window.location.reload();

        if ( resolve ) {
          resolve( true );
        }

      }
    }, err => {
      console.log( err );
      this.message.type = 'danger';
      this.message.body = 'Visit Creation failed, please try again later.';
      if ( reject ) {
        reject( false );
      }

    } );
  }

  updateVisit(resolve?, reject?) {
    console.log( 'update Obj', this.visitObj );
    this.visitService.updatePatientVisit( this.visitObj, this.visitObj.id ).subscribe( res => {
      console.log( 'res-obj-updated', res );

      if ( res.success ) {
        this.message.type = 'success';
        this.message.body = 'Visit update Successfully';
        window.location.reload();

        if ( resolve ) {
          resolve( true );
        }

      }
    }, err => {
      console.log( err );
      this.message.type = 'danger';
      this.message.body = 'Updating the visit failed, please try again.';

      if ( reject ) {
        reject( false );
      }

    } );
  }

  saveBeforeNavigation(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      if ( this.createObj ) {
        this.createVisit(resolve, reject);
      } else {
        this.updateVisit(resolve, reject);
      }
    } );
  }

  formErrors = {
    visitDate: '',
    weight: '',
    height: '',
    lowPressure: '',
    highPressure: '',
    heartRate: '',
    temp: '',
    surg: '',
    dent: '',
    phys: '',
    ortha: '',
    labAss: '',
    imag: '',
    trans: '',
    treat: '',
    lastComp: '',
  };

  validationMessages = {
    visitDate: {
      'required': 'Regimen Date is required.',
    },
    weight: {
      'required': ' Type is required.',
    },
    height: {
      'required': ' Drug Name is required.',
    },
    lowPressure: {},
    highPressure: {},
    heartRate: {},
    temp: {},
    surg: {},
    dent: {},
    phys: {},
    ortha: {},
    labAss: {},
    imag: {},
    trans: {},
    treat: {},
    lastComp: {},

  };

  beforeSaveValidation( url ) {
    let confirm = window.confirm( 'Save changes?' );

    if ( confirm ) {
      this.saveBeforeNavigation().then( whenResolve => {
        this.route.navigate( [url] );
      }, whenReject => {
        alert( 'couldn\'t save the data. Server error occurred' );
      } );
    }
  }
}
```

my angular-cli version is: 1.0.4

**EDIT**

This is the visitInfo Template:

```
<ba-card [title]="Visit"  baCardClass="with-scroll">
<div class="widgets">

  <form (ngSubmit)="submitVisit()" [formGroup]="myForm">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-3">
          <label class="control-label">Date Of Visit</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control col-9" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.visitDate"
                 formControlName="visitDate" id="visitDate">
        </div>
      </div>
      <ba-card title="Vital Signs" baCardClass="with-scroll">

        <div id="profile">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Weight (KG)</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control col-6" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.weight" formControlName="weight" id="weight">
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.weight" class="col-3 alert alert-danger">
                {{ formErrors.weight }}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-2">
              <label class="control-label">Height (cm)</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control col-6" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.height" formControlName="height" id="height">
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.height" class="col-3 alert alert-danger">
                {{ formErrors.height }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-3">
              <label>Blood Pressure (mmHg)</label>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.bloodPressureHigh" formControlName="highPressure" id="highPressure">
                  <div *ngIf="formErrors.highPressure" class="col-3 alert alert-danger">
                    {{ formErrors.highPressure }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 text-center"><span class="h3">/</span></div>
                <div class="col-5">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.bloodPressureLow" formControlName="lowPressure" id="lowPressure">
                  <div *ngIf="formErrors.lowPressure" class="col-3 alert alert-danger">
                    {{ formErrors.lowPressure }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-2">
              <label>Heart Rate (bpm)</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control col-6" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.heartRate" formControlName="heartRate" id="heartRate">
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.heartRate" class="col-3 alert alert-danger">
                {{ formErrors.heartRate }}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-2">
              <label>Temperature (&deg;C)</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control col-6" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.temperature" formControlName="temp" id="temp">
              <div *ngIf="formErrors.temp" class="col-3 alert alert-danger">
                {{ formErrors.temp }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ba-card>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>
        <ba-card title="Did the patient undergo any of the following since last visit?" baCardClass="with-scroll">

          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.surgicalOperationProcedures" [label]="'Surgical/operation procedures'"
                             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ba-checkbox>
              </div>

              <div class="checkbox">
                <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.dentalProcedures" [label]="'Dental procedures'"
                             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"> </ba-checkbox>
              </div>


              <div class="checkbox">
                <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.physiotherapyProcedures" [label]="'Physiotherapy'"
                             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ba-checkbox>
              </div>

              <div class="checkbox">
                <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.orthopedicProcedures" [label]="'Orthopedic procedures'"
                             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ba-checkbox>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group"
                   *ngIf="visitObj.surgicalOperationProcedures || visitObj.dentalProcedures || visitObj.physiotherapyProcedures || visitObj.orthopedicProcedures">
                <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="beforeSaveValidation('/pages/patient/patientInfo/intervention')">Edit</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="checkbox col-6">
                  <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.labAssessmentsProcedures" [label]="'Lab assessments'"
                               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ba-checkbox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div *ngIf="visitObj.labAssessmentsProcedures">
                    <span class=" edit-btn">
                      <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="beforeSaveValidation('/pages/patient/patientInfo/labAssessments')"> Edit </a>
                    </span>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.imagingProcedures" [label]="'Imaging procedures'"
                                 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ba-checkbox>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div *ngIf="visitObj.imagingProcedures">
                    <span class=" edit-btn">
                      <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="beforeSaveValidation('/pages/patient/patientInfo/imaging')"> Edit </a>
                    </span>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
        </ba-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>
        <ba-card title="Since last visit, did the patient receive any of the following:" baCardClass="with-scroll">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.transfusionLastVisit" [label]="'Transfusions'"
                               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ba-checkbox>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div *ngIf="visitObj.transfusionLastVisit">
                  <span class=" edit-btn">
                    <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="beforeSaveValidation('/pages/patient/patientInfo/transfusion')"> Edit </a>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <ba-checkbox [(ngModel)]="visitObj.treatmentLastVisit" [label]="'Treatment (New/Modified)'"
                               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ba-checkbox>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div *ngIf="visitObj.treatmentLastVisit">
                  <span class=" edit-btn">
                    <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="beforeSaveValidation('/pages/patient/patientInfo/treatment')"> Edit </a>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </ba-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>
        <ba-card title="Since last visit, did the patient suffer from new complications/Adverse events?"
                 baCardClass="with-scroll">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-demo radio-demo row">

              <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="radio-inline custom-radio nowrap">
                  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.complicationLastVisit"  [value]="1"
                         formControlName="lastComp" >
                  <span>Yes</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="radio-inline custom-radio nowrap">
                  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="visitObj.complicationLastVisit"  [value]="2"
                         formControlName="lastComp" >
                  <span>No</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="visitObj.complicationLastVisit == 1">
              <a  class="btn btn-primary" (click)="beforeSaveValidation('/pages/patient/patientInfo/complications')">Edit</a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </ba-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <button type="submit" *ngIf="createObj" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Save</button>
      <button *ngIf="!createObj" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Update</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

  <message-com [message]="message"></message-com>

</ba-card>
```

And here is the Visit Model used:

```
import * as models from './models';

export class Visit {
  id?: number;

  visitDate?: Date;

  weight?: number;

  height?: number;

  bloodPressureLow?: number;

  bloodPressureHigh?: number;

  heartRate?: number;

  temperature?: number;

  surgicalOperationProcedures?: boolean;

  dentalProcedures?: boolean;

  physiotherapyProcedures?: boolean;

  orthopedicProcedures?: boolean;

  labAssessmentsProcedures?: boolean;

  imagingProcedures?: boolean;

  transfusionLastVisit?: boolean;

  treatmentLastVisit?: boolean;

  complicationLastVisit?: number;

  patientId?: number;

  userId?: number;

  constructor() {
    this.visitDate = new Date();
    this.surgicalOperationProcedures = false;
    this.dentalProcedures = false;
    this.physiotherapyProcedures = false;
    this.orthopedicProcedures = false;
    this.labAssessmentsProcedures = false;
    this.imagingProcedures = false;
    this.transfusionLastVisit = false;
    this.treatmentLastVisit = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: I suspect your template is trying reference `Visit`, but it was removed or never existed on the component in the first place -- did you mean `visitObj`?. Also, make sure any variable used in the template is declared as `public`, not `private`. You could post your template to be sure.

Comment: The Visit is a Model file, I included it up in the post.
And its used as a type for `visitObj`.
I believe if access modifier not assigned in Typescript, it is by default public, Am I right? @LyingCake

Comment: Unfortunately that's beyond my knowledge of Typescript. If it were me, I'd try setting `visitObj: Visit;` to `public visitObj: Visit;`, but I can't guarantee that will solve anything. Best of luck.

Comment: I tried making all the properties public, but nothing changed.
I have updated my question and included the model and the template.
Thanks for your help @LyingCake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is being caused by the title attribute in the first line of your template

```
<ba-card [title]="Visit"  baCardClass="with-scroll">
```

Here, you are telling Angular to search for a property called *Visit*, but the VisitInfoComponent have no property named like that, I guess you probably wanted the title to be Visit, you have three options.

1. You could remove the brackets, using `title="Visit"` or
2. You could use quotes to say you need a string `[title]="'Visit'"` or
3. You need a property named *Visit* in your component, which I think is not your case

Thing is, when you use brackets, you tell Angular to bind that attribute to a variable, not plain text.